# Sanitize input yields a blank safe string

Tags: php

I have a database built and working for my music collection.  I have built an entry page that only I have access to.  Obviously when I have a title or artist with an apostrophe the entry fails.  I've been reading and I found this syntax on a page on this site.  However when I try to execute it the 'safe' stringer comes out blank.

This is the part of the code that doesn't work.  I'm sure it's something stupid I've done.  If anyone can point out the error of my ways I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
$artist=$_POST['artist'];
    echo $artist . "<br>";
    $safeartist = mysqli_real_escape_string($artist);
    echo $safeartist . "<br>";  
$title=$_POST['title'];
    $safetitle = mysql_real_escape_string($title);
    echo $safetitle . "<br>";
```

It does in fact have the data in the 'echo artist' command but does not for the second echo.

Comment: You mix `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`. That said, are you sure that you're connected to your database?

Comment: If you are using MySQLi, don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, use prepared statements and bind variables

Comment: use `error_reporting(E_WARNING);` as @h2ooooooo says you may not be connected to the db

Comment: Folks thanks for your efforts.  I can see I am just over my head here.  I've been trying to learn this on my own and to be honest I'm getting a headache.  [Grin]--You are right that I mixed mysql and mysqli.  I was trying both back and forth and for some reason on the last one I only changed one.  I'm sorry but I haven't been able to grasp prepared statements.  I've looked for a classroom course but there are none in my area.  I'm gonna try to see if I can find a book to help.  BTW all the other fields were writing to the DB so Yes I am connected.  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to print the string in the DOM it might be that you are looking for `htmlentities`

http://www.php.net/htmlentities

mysql_* is deprecated PDO is often a more reasonable choice http://php.net/PDO